# Programmatically fire windows joystick events?

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, joystick, directinput

**Problem**

I want to programmatically throw 
[Windows Joystick move events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757352%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using c++, but I am unsure how.

Someone had mentioned writing my own custom device driver. I've never done anything like that before.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**What have I tried?**

**1)**
I first looked into [VJoy](http://vjoystick.sourceforge.net/site/index.php/77-vjoy/84-homepage-v200) and it's [SDK](http://vjoystick.sourceforge.net/site/index.php/81-news/104-vjoy-2-1-5-sdk-released) as a way to do this.

I ran the demo code but it required the Vjoy driver installed. I tried to do this but received a "[Procedure Entry Point Not Found in Msvcrt.dll File](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324762) " error causing the installation to fail.

The suggested fix by Microsoft was to...

> ...use the Windows XP Recovery Console to replace the Msvcrt.dll file
>   with the original version.

(I believe the Msvcrt.dll Version should be 7.0.2600.0 but mine is 7.0.2600.5512.)

This required a Windows XP CD-ROM, which I do not have.

**2)** I had thought I could maybe achieve the same thing with the DirectX DirectInput component follwoing this [tutorial](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~jparise/directx/joystick/). I also installed the [DirectX SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=6812) to get the .lib files and headerfiles I needed.

The tutorial said:

> You'll need to include the DirectInput header file in order to use any
>   of the DirectInput functions:
>
> `#include <dinput.h>`
>
> In order to link a final application binary, you'll need to include
>   the following following libraries in your project:
>
> `dinput8.lib dxguid.lib`

I linked the librarys correctly but when I included dinput.h and built I received the following errors

```
1>  Main.cpp
1>  c:\program files\microsoft directx sdk (june 2010)\include\dinput.h: DIRECTINPUT_VERSION undefined. Defaulting to version 0x0800
1>c:\program files\microsoft directx sdk (june 2010)\include\dinput.h(1991): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>c:\program files\microsoft directx sdk (june 2010)\include\dinput.h(1991): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft directx sdk (june 2010)\include\dinput.h(1999): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>c:\program files\microsoft directx sdk (june 2010)\include\dinput.h(1999): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft directx sdk (june 2010)\include\dinput.h(2220): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>c:\program files\microsoft directx sdk (june 2010)\include\dinput.h(2220): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft directx sdk (june 2010)\include\dinput.h(2232): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>c:\program files\microsoft directx sdk (june 2010)\include\dinput.h(2232): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

**Some extra info**

I am using Windows XP.

I am a c++ novice.

Comment: If I'm unclear at any point or my tags are incorrect etc, let me know so I can try improve the question.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you suggest some improvements with your downvote please?

Comment: You need to use something like VJoy, DirectInput won't help you.  In order to resolve your problem with installing VJoy, try containing the developers as instructed on this page: http://vjoystick.sourceforge.net/site/index.php/download-a-install/80-install-x86x64

Comment: @RossRidge thanks I'll give that a try, appreciate it